# Is there any limit on the number of boards returned by the pinterest rest api?

Tags: javascript, limit, pinterest

when fetching boards for the user which I have logged in with PDK.login() function provided in the JavaScript SDK of Pinterest.

Since there is a limit on the number of pins returned by the Pinterest, I was wondering if there is any limit on the number of boards returned by the rest api for boards as well.

Any help would be appreciated! The documentation at Pinterest is not very user friendly and hence I am forced to ask this question!

Comment: How about you try a really big number and see what happens?

Comment: I don't think so, and there is no pagination for boards either. :(

Comment: @DaveNewton In this case I will have to create 500 boards (the limit for creating boards! :- P )